# how can i open a photoshop file in illustrator without loosing quality?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects, import

I tried to open a photoshop file with an effect (outer glow) applied in Illustrator. However when I opened the file, the effect which I applied to the image didn't come out as the same in Photoshop. The color of the outer glow effect changed. Can anyone please help me with this problem? Many thanks !!!

Comment: CMYK document VS RGB file perhaps

Answer (score 0):

The way that Illustrator and Photoshop handle effects is different, so some effects will always look strange when you go from one to the other.  In cases like these, your best bet is to either rasterize the image completely (thus importing it as a transparent .png) or try to manually recreate the effect in Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outer glow from your photoshop file and reapply it within Illustrator. Using Effect > Stylize > Outer Glow. Worth a shot.